# php7.1 store file and retrieve file from mongdb 1.2.8

Tags: php, mongodb, file

Need help in dealing with files in php7.1 mongodb(1.2.8)

we are able to insert and fetch normal records(like id, name) in php7.1 mongodb1.28. 
need to know how we can store files and retrieve files in mongodb with php7.1

// Connect to Mongo and set DB and Collection

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->myfiles;

// GridFS
$grid = $db->getGridFS();

// The file's location in the File System
$path = "/tmp/";

$filename = "filename.txt";

// Note metadata field & filename field
$storedfile = $grid->storeFile($path . $filename, array("metadata" => array("filename" => $filename),"filename" => $filename));

// Return newly stored file's Document ID
echo $storedfile;
```

looking similar in php7.1

appreciates your help

thanks
Naren

Comment: Did you read http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.selectdb.php ?

Comment: You can try https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/gridfs/

Comment: thanks guys, finally after lot of hiccups found the way to store files with php7

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPLIB-51